# Missing 'Cart' page content in WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

After a few days without updating website, there's the trouble with missing cart content.
[click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fdyw.png)
Everything that's loading is header. You can see it on the screenshot.
I checked whether shortcode [woocommerce_cart] is there. It is. I tried to change theme from custom to clean Storefront theme and it is still not showing any content of cart, when there are any items.
If there's no items in cart, it is showing "Your basket is currently empty.". Вut when I add any product in cart, the cart page content disappears.
What can i do with that? Any ideas?

Comment: Judging by the image you provided it looks like a fatal error, probably a plugin, start disabling plugins one by one until you find the culprit. You could also check the error_log if you have access to the site files, you could add `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );` in `wp-config.php` (if site not live) and see the error PHP outputs.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast hello, I've already tried to disable all the plugins and even change the theme, but it didn't fix this issue. 
Also, i tried to define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); and there's no errors in the cart page.
Looks like magic.

Comment: Try adding `define( 'WP_DEBUG_LOG', true );` to `wp-config.php` and checking the debug_log located in `/wp-content/debug.log file`, this enables WordPress built in debug log and should help you find the problem.

Comment: @Buttered_Toast tried this one, and there's no errors from cart page in /wp-content/debug.log file

Comment: UPD: I solved id.
WooCommerce -> Status -> Tools
I cleared there everything. After that i deactivated WooCommerce and activated again. So the cart works now. It seems to be problems after Woo updated/